# Search SQLite DB for DateType via String - Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I currently use a SQLite database in an existing Android project.

In an EditText-Field I'm able to search for different attributes of the item, like color, or title or amount. So for every typed letter, the search-suggestion update. In my Item-Entitiy I've different attributes, here a simple example:

```
 Item:
 * String: color
 * String: title
 * int: price
 * Date: date
 * int: id
```

So in my search-field I'd like to mind all of those attributes. This is working for my String- as well as my int-Attributes, but I cant manage to filter for the Date-datatype.

If I type "18" in the TextEditField, i'd like to get all items from 2018, all items from the 18. March 1974, all items with the title "18 tipps for sql-queries" and all items with a price starting from 18,00 to 18,99 - and of course every xx,18.

My current Query in my ItemDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE (LOWER(color) LIKE :searchtext OR LOWER(title) LIKE :searchtext OR price LIKE :searchtext) ORDER BY date DESC")
public abstract List<ItemEntity> searchItems(String searchtext);
```

How can I accopmlish that I'm also able to search for the datetype? 
I tried to include `strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) LIKE :searchtext`

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve my problem, I've added an additional line in my query to search in the dates as well:

```
OR LOWER(strftime('%d.%m.%Y', datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch', '+1 day'))) LIKE :searchtext
```

After digging into my db i've seen that the date is saved as a timestamp containing the time component in milliseconds, therefore it was necessary to divide the initial timestamp by 1000. After that I've a timestamp in the UNIX Epoche format, that's why I define it as 'unixepoche'.
The last attribute adds 1 day to the loaded date, because the %d configuration starts by zero. So the first of January '19 without the '+1 day' would be converted into 00.01.2019.